# If statement not working in my code. the variable is not tested

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

In PHP I have used:

```
if($a=="no" or $curriculum=="yes")
```

Do you find anything wrong with that `if` statement?

It displays the contents of `if` even when `$a = yes` and `$curriculum = no`..
I have done enough checks to check whether the variables have the correct value..
Please help!!

Comment: It depends on how you expect the `or` precedence to work versus `||`.

Comment: It's simply not possible for the language to mess up a simple if like that, let's see your complete code related to that `if`

Comment: @AlexW: `or` has lower precedence than `||`. The code he pasted is fine. The bug is somewhere else.

Comment: Alex W it is not possible that this is a precedence issue. In such a case `OR` will work same as `||`

Comment: maybe it should be `AND` and not `OR`?

Comment: When you are using strings make sure its not a case issue 'Yes' is not equal to 'yes'

Comment: And also make sure that you dont' have `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Come on Guy, people are so eager to help you out and you aren't updating!

Comment: It seems he was away from keyboard.

Comment: Why am I the first one to close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
if($a=="no" || $curriculum=="yes")
```

Comment: Using `or` or `||` does not matter in this case. Both work equally fine. ( Did you test this before answering? )

Comment: i thought that this code should work. i didn't test it. i'll aware from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here are some tests.
Your if statement is fine ( `or` works as well as `||` does in this case )

```
$a = 'abc';
$curriculum = 'abc';
if($a == "no" or $curriculum == "yes") {
    echo 'Either $a equals "no" or $curriculum equals "yes"<br>'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Neither $a equals "no" nor does $curriculum equal "yes"<br>'.PHP_EOL;
}

$a = 'no';
$curriculum = 'abc';
if($a == "no" or $curriculum == "yes") {
    echo 'Either $a equals "no" or $curriculum equals "yes"<br>'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Neither $a equals "no" nor does $curriculum equal "yes"<br>'.PHP_EOL;
}

$a = 'abc';
$curriculum = 'yes';
if($a == "no" or $curriculum == "yes") {
    echo 'Either $a equals "no" or $curriculum equals "yes"<br>'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Neither $a equals "no" nor does $curriculum equal "yes"<br>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

These result in:

```
Neither $a equals "no" nor does $curriculum equal "yes"
Either $a equals "no" or $curriculum equals "yes"
Either $a equals "no" or $curriculum equals "yes"
```

Please do a var_dump of both variables right before the if statement and show us the results:

```
var_dump($a);
var_dump($curriculum);
if($a == "no" or $curriculum == "yes") {
```

Comment: My problem has gotten solved!! Thanks guys..